# Build multiple project configurations with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, maven-2

Is there a way to make Eclipse able to export multiple configurations of 
a single project?

My problem is the following:

I have several java web applications which I develop in Eclipse.
Before I put new versions onto my production server I publish the
new versions to a test server, where the apps run with a slightly
different configuration (database server name, etc.).

Is there a way to something like 'export war for TEST env'
and 'export war for PROD env'? Eclipse only would have to
take another properties file...

I guess there is a way, I just can't figure it out.

Any ideas / hints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually plugins for this out there:

[Maven4Eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html)

Answer (score 2):

You would get much better results by having an [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) build.

These are build systems, rather than IDEs, so all you have to do is run a shell command, with parameters, if needed.

---

*Update*: as for the question of integrating Ant or Maven with Eclipse, see my answer on [Best way to share jars across multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988812/whats-the-best-way-to-share-jars-across-multiple-projects/988861#988861).

Comment: ic, I was just wondering whether there's an option of integrating these tools with eclipse...