# Best way to share JARS in a eclipse with JBOSS as the App Server

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jar, shared-libraries

Looking for a solution so that I can have a central location for all my JAR files plus still be able to do a deploy to JBOSS inside Eclipse.

I have a LIB fold out side my projects.  I have add the required libs to a given directory using Eclipse build path external jar.  But, when I run the application on JBOSS inside Eclipse it does not start.  It would seem that JBOSS expects to find the required JAR files under WEB-INF/lib.  I have tried other things as well, such as creating a manifest file in the EAR but that did not work.

I looked at the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988812/whats-the-best-way-to-share-jars-across-multiple-projects) but it does not address running the application with JBOSS inside Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What i have done, is put the jar inside the WEB-INF folder under libs. That is where JBoss expects to find all jars required for that project.

Comment: Right, but my hope is that I can place the jars in a central and that all my web applications can then get the files from there.  What I am trying to avoid is having duplicate jars through out all my web apps.

Comment: If its in the same Project you shouldn't have a problem with that. however if you have multiple projects then you'll have to have more then 1 copy

Comment: Yea, that is where I am at right now, was hoping that there was a way in which I can have a central location for my libs and then each project can just include what they need.  Alternative is to create a list of jars and create an ant task that will copy over the ones that are required into a given project.

Comment: Im sorry i do not think that is possible. :(